# How to import saved Python ML Model into Node js Using Tensorflow Js

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, node-modules

I want to import an saved Python machine learning model into Nodejs for an web application based prediction.

**What have been done so far :**

Converted the saved model into json file format :

Tried to import the saved file into nodejs file using :

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const model = tf.loadLayersModel('C:\Users\Desktop\Prod\cate\model.json');
```

Executed the file using command line:

**Getting the error :**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '@tensorflow/tfjs-core'

**Required Stack:**

C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\constraints.js
C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\exports_constraints.js
C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js
C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\script.js

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\tfjs\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\constraints.js:26:11)

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

Comment: Maybe you can keep the python script and call it using node as a child process

Comment: Have you tried npm i . It's a silly question but people forget about sometimes

Comment: @AvivLo - I have tried using npm, but still the same result .